# Expandable/Collapsible icon menu

Tags: angular, icons, angular8, expandable

I am developing an angular 8 web application where i am required to have a expandable/collapsible icon menu which will display a single icon, and when clicked on it, it will expand to display more icons which will act as menu. Is there any libraries i could use or should i write my own animation. Please refer the image for details.
[image]

I want the border to be curve as shown in the picture. What can be done to achieve the following output.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite site for inspiration is [codepen](https://codepen.io/), but u can find many [more](https://www.sitepoint.com/7-code-playgrounds/). I search for something [similar](https://codepen.io/dineshdesign/pen/ZOywEb) and transform to angular with [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) and [HostListener](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener).

```
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/dineshdesign/pen/ZOywEb)
```